# Jquery - How to hide link if element inside is empty (white space)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem to hide element if span inside is with empty space as text. Is it possible to hide. I've tried code below without result ? Thank you.

Jquery:

```
if($('#footerextra .link3 .ui-btn-inner .ui-btn-text').is(':empty')){
   $(this).closest(.link3).hide();
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="footerextra" class="ui-footer ui-bar-b" data-theme="b" data-role="footer" style="width=100%; text-align:center; margin: 0 auto;" role="contentinfo">
     <a class="link3 ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-b" href="/cz/cs/80_automobilovy-prumysl/1191_vyroba-automobilovych-dveri.html?do=article" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="b">
       <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
         <span class="ui-btn-text"> </span>
       </span>
     </a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **[.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/)** to loop through your `span` elements in order to utilize `$(this)` here:

```
$('#footerextra .link3 .ui-btn-inner .ui-btn-text').each(function () {
    if ($.trim($(this).text()) == 0) {
        $(this).closest('.link3').hide();
    }
});
```

Also since your `span` got a space in the HTML markup, you can use **[jQuery.trim()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)** to remove the whitespace from the text of your span.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7sMe3/)**

Comment: Why would you conclude that `.each()` is even necessary? OP's sample code only has one instance.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems

```
$('#footerextra .link3').filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).find('.ui-btn-inner .ui-btn-text').text()).length ==0
}).hide()
```

- The `.ui-btn-text` is not empty because it has an empty space(text node) as a child
- inside the if block `this` does not refer to the `ui-btn-text` element so `$(this).closest(.link3)` does not make any sense
- `$(this).closest(.link3)` - you are missing to enclose `link3` in `''`

Answer (score 0):

$(this) here not is reference to '.ui-btn-text':

```
if($('#footerextra .link3 .ui-btn-inner .ui-btn-text').is(':empty')){
   $(this).closest(.link3).hide();
}
```

And put quotes in '.link3'.

You can do this:

```
if($('#footerextra .link3 .ui-btn-inner .ui-btn-text').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':empty')){
        $(this).closest(.link3).hide();
    }
});
```

But this only loop through to '.ui-btn-text' inside a same '.ui-btn-inner'.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

Jquery:

```
   $('#id1').hide();
```

HTML:

```
< a id="id1" ></a>
```